# How can i read 10 bytes from memory to add each consecutive 2 bytes

Tags: assembly, 68000, easy68k

I have stored the string '0123456789', so now the ASCII value of each character is stored as one byte in the memory, How can  add each consecutive 2 bytes like the following:

0+1->1, 1+2->2........etc

```
“0123456789”
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
00000000 00000001 00000010 00000011 00000100 00000101 00000110 00000111 00001000 00001001

00010001
00001111 
00001101
00001011
00001001
00000111
00000101
00000011
00000001
00000000
```

My first try was something like this

```
ORG     $1000
START:          DC.L    '0123456789'        
                MOVE.L  #$1000, A1

                MOVE.B  (A1)+, D0
                MOVE.B  (A1)+, D1
                MOVE.B  (A1)+, D2
                MOVE.B  (A1)+, D3
                MOVE.B  (A1)+, D4
                MOVE.B  (A1)+, D6
                MOVE.B  (A1)+, D6
                MOVE.B  (A1)+, D7



    SIMHALT            



    END    START
```

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, the values stored as character codes, not integers.

So to add them, you must convert to integer by subtracting '0'. Let's assume you use a platform where the decimal digits are encoded in sequential codes (like C requires, for instance). This is common.

Here's a sub-routine that adds two such digits, pointed to by `a1` as in your code, and returning the sum in `d1`. It only advances a single character, so if you do this in a loop you will sum first index 0 and 1, then index 1 and 2, and so on.

```
sum_two:
   move.b (a1)+,d1
   subi.b #'0',d1
   add.b  (a1),d1
   subi.b #'0',d1
   rts
```

Note: It's been `BIGNUM` years since I last wrote MC68k assembly, so I might have some detail off.